# How to set zoom level of Google Map according to the number of latitude and longitude so that to fit all the points on screen. I need a c# code

Tags: c#, google-maps

How to set zoom level of Google Map according to the number of latitude and longitude so that  to fit all the points on screen.   I need  a c# code.

```
this is map

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="Panel2" UpdateMode="Conditional" EnableViewState="True">
    <ContentTemplate>
       <div id="div_map" runat="server" style="vertical-align: middle">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <uc1:GoogleMapForASPNet ID="GoogleMapForASPNet1" runat="server" />
</div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a similar question here: http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/e6448fc197c3c892

anyway here's sample code for your question:

```
    var latlngList = [];
latlngList.push(new google.maps.LatLng (lat,lng));

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
latlngList.each(function(n){
   bounds.extend(n);
});

map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter()); //or use custom center
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

and here's an optional trick:

```
//remove one zoom level to ensure no marker is on the edge.
map.setZoom(map.getZoom()-1); 

// set a minimum zoom 
// if you got only 1 marker or all markers are on the same address map will be zoomed too much.
if(map.getZoom()> 15){
  map.setZoom(15);
}
```

Comment: sir ... I need a C# code . I am Using GoogleMapForASPNet . I displayed all the pushpins . I am beginner. I have done all in C#.  so Kindly share some c# code to do this.